# NotificationCenter not trigger when call Quick Action

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch, quickaction

I implemented 3D Touch Quick Action in app when call function `performActionForShortcutItem` in `AppDelegate`, I triggering by `NotificationCenter` inside it but not work and call

my Code in `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor 
shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping 
(Bool) -> Void) {


    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("action"), object: nil);

}
```

and used it `ViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();


    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(BaseViewController.didReceiveNotification), name: Notification.Name("action"), object: nil);
}

func didReceiveNotification() {
    let alert = UIAlert(viewController: self);
    alert.content = "NotificationCenter Worked";
    alert.title = "NotificationCenter here!!";
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: Is your ViewController Loaded at the time you post your Notification? Because the addObserver must be executed before you post something... Did you try to print() if viewDidLoad is Executed before performActionForShortcutItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `ViewController`  is not yet loaded so the observer is not yet add to it

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(BaseViewController.didReceiveNotification), name: Notification.Name("action"), object: nil);
```

you can try to set a boolean value inside`performActionForshortcutItem` and check it inside viewDidAppear of `ViewController`

Comment: Thats what I thought too @Alireza

Comment: @DennisWeidmann I define `addObserver` in `viewDidAppear` & `viewWillAppear` but not work both.

Comment: @AlirezaTarazani Sure it won't work , can you try to delay the post un til app is active or store a boolean as in answer ??

Comment: @Sh_Khan I think `performActionForshortcutItem` run earlier than `ViewController`

Comment: yes , this is the idea you can verify it with a print , either you set a flag inside performActionForshortcutItem or delay the post , but solution one is granted

Comment: Take a look at my answer, I show you how to do it like @Sh_Khan and I told you

Answer (score 2):

Your Problem is like Sh_Khan said, that you can't post on AppDelegate to a ViewController, because at this time your ViewController didn't subscribe to the Notification...

You need to do something like this:

In your AppDelegate

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping(Bool) -> Void) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "openedByShortcutAction")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
```

In your ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if (UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "openedByShortcutAction")) {
            //Your App has been started by selecting your Shortcut Action
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes that's right , this is what i already told him in answer (voted)

Comment: @Sh_Khan thanks My friends but I want handle it by `NotificationCenter` and I don't like use flag or var. but no way !

Comment: Well you can't handle it by NotificationCenter mate :-)

Comment: Yes, there is no 100% guarantee it that it can be correctly handled by notificationCenter , one way is to use dispatchAfter to delay the postNotification call , but the time you set can span(either more or less than ) the time the viewController is loaded